# How to "lock" the position of a component on react native screen?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to build the profile screen of a user on my social networking app. The way I want it is the top 1/3 of the screen is the user profile information, and the bottom 2/3 is a flatlist of all the user's posts. Currently, I have that all working logic wise. Here is a screenshot from the app:

[image]

As you can see, the user profile information is displaying up top, and the user's post history is correctly being displayed in a flat list below. However, the flat list is pushing the user profile information "up" on the screen.

Here is the code for the profile:

```
class Profile extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        user: this.props.user
    }
    
}

goToSettings = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Settings')
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", padding: 20 }}>
                <Text style = {styles.subheader}> {this.state.user.username} </Text> <------The username is being pushed up, where only the bottom half of it is visible

                <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress={this.goToSettings}>
                    <Ionicons name="ios-settings" size={24} color="black" />
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>



            <View style = {styles.lineStyle} />
            
            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <ProfilePic/> 
                <ProfileStats/>
            </View>

            <View style = {styles.lineStyle} />

            <ProfileBio />

            <View style = {styles.lineStyle} />
            
            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <CurrentUserPostFeed navigation = {this.props.navigation} /> <------ This is the flat list. It is pushing up the views & other components that are above it.
            </View>           

        </View>
    )
}
}
```

**I want the position of the user profile information to stay in the same postition, taking up the top 1/3 of the screen, while the user can scroll through the flatlist which only takes up the bottom 2/3 of the screen**

However, I am not sure how to "lock" the profile information in place, where it is always visible in the top 1/3 of the profile screen, no matter how big/small the flatlist of posts becomes. Any advice?

EDIT: It seems that the margin/padding in the cells of the flatlist are causing my issue. Is there a way that I can prevent the flatlist container from pushing the elements above it "up" when I add marginTop or paddingTop?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `flex` property to set which

> specifies how much of the remaining space in the flex container should be assigned to the item

More info about the `flex` property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow).
** `flex` is a shorthand for `flex-grow`.

So, you can do something like this:

```
<View> // main container
    <View style={{flex: 1}}> // header container
       // Header Content
    </View>
    <View style={{flex: 2}}> // flatlist container
        // Flatlist content
    </View>
</View>
```

Basically what we are doing here is setting the `header` to use 1/3 of the available space of `main-container` and `flatlist` to use 2/3 of the available sapce of the `main-container`.

Comment: This kind of worked. I set the flex: 1 for the header, but setting flex: 2 for the flatlist causes it to be placed on top of the header. Instead, I set flex: 1 position: absolute for the header container and marginTop: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.24, for the flatlist container. This works nicely